# How to block access to file directory via browser?

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, debian, vps

I use VPS hosting and Debian, then i installed Wordpress. I upload file in one specific file and unfortunately it is accessiblevia browser:

```
qartulad.online/wp-content/movies/2018/
```

People can access to every file on this directory. But people cannot access to other Wordpress directory:

```
qartulad.online/wp-content/
```

How can i block access to my specific directory too?

How is the access on this domain blocked?

```
ftp01.srulad.net/hd3/cfb32710293800d2c041409ae665c998/
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple ways to do this.

You can do it on the server level via the httpd.conf or .htaccess. (httpd is the best spot to do it)

In the httpd.conf

Look for Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

Change it to Options FollowSymLinks

In the .htaccess add before the WordPress block.

Options -Indexes

There are also plugins that will do it. iTheme Security has more or less a one click that does a lot of the basic security like directory surfing etc.

Comment: Where can i find httpd.conf on wordpres? and in .htacess i have only this code:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: It really depends on your host. They may have it moved into a different location. I would recommend contacting their support.